# Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "web": "SECRET_KEY=

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am working on online book store project.
I am trying to setup environment variables in dockercompose.yml

*project_folder/settings.py*

`SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')`

*The code inside dockercompose.yml file*

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
      build: .
      command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      volumes:
          - .:/code
      ports:
          - 8000:8000
      depends_on:
          - db
      environment:
          - SECRET_KEY=my_secret_key
          - DEBUG=1

  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I am getting the following error when I ran the command

```
$docker-compose down

ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "web": "SECRET_KEY=my_secret_key"
```

Comment: Is there $ symbol in your `my_secret_key` ?

Comment: yes $ symbol is there.

Comment: do you think i need to remove the $ symbol where ever it is in my secret key?

Answer (score 22):

As your secret_key contains `$` symbol. You need to escape it.

Escape it using double $ symbol `$$` as specified [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) in official doc.

Or if possible you can just have a new secret_key without `$` symbol in it.